# show that every integer and every angle ... pendulum moving around the circle at least n times but not n+1 times

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

For the nonlinear damped pendulum, show that for every integer $n$ and every angle $θ_0$ there is an initial condition $(θ_0 , v_0)$ with a solution that corresponds to the pendulum moving around the circle at least n times, but not n + 1 times, before settling down to the rest position.

I am given a solution below...could anyone tell me what is the key in the solution and could you present the logic for this solution in a more concise way for me to understand as I read this several times and I still do not quite get what is going on?

Solution: We claim that for $u> 0$ small enough, $( − π,u )$ lies in the basin of attraction of the equilibrium $(0 , 0)$. This is true for $( θ,u )$ for $θ ∈ ( − π,π )$; for $θ = − π$ , it is not hard to show that for all small enough $t> 0$, $θ ( t )$ > $− π $and $v ( t)$ is small enough so that $( θ(t),v(t))$ lies in the basin of attraction of $(0,0)$ which proves the claim.

Now consider the energy function $E(θ, v) = 1/2 v^2 + 1 − cos θ$. We have $E' = vv' + (sin θ)θ' = −bv^2 $ which is always nonpositive. So for any solution, energy does not increase as t increases; this holds even for negative values for t. Consider the solution $( θ(t),v(t))$ determined by $(θ(0), v(0)) = (−π, u)$.

For all $t ≤ 0$, $$E(θ(t), v(t)) ≥ E(2πn, u)$$ $$1/2v(t)^2 + 1 − cos θ(t) ≥ 1/2u^2+2$$ `should not this be 1?` $$1/2v(t)^2  ≥ 1/2u^2 + 1 + cos θ$$

$$≥ 1/2u^2$$ Thus $v(t) ≥ u > 0$ for all $t ≤ 0$.

Suppose that the solution is defined for all time. Since $θ' (t) ≥ u$ for all $t, θ → −∞$ as $t → −∞$. Then given $n ∈ N$ and $angle θ_0$ , we can find $t_0$ such that $θ(t_0) ∈ (−(2n + 2)π, −2nπ]$ and $θ(t_0 ) ≡ θ_0$ mod 2π (clearly adding multiples of 2π to θ just gives a translate of the solution). Now just put $v_0 = v(t_0)$. It now just remains to consider the case when the solution is only defined on an interval $(a, b)$. Then as $t → a$, either $θ → −∞$ or $v → −∞$; otherwise we would be able to extend the solution to its limit at $t = a$. If $θ → −∞$, we can proceed as before. Finally we claim $v → ∞$ is impossible. Since $v' = −bv − sin θ$ and $v(t) > 0$ for all $t ≤ 0$, $|v'| ≤ bv + 1$; the solution to $v' = −bv − 1$ is bounded for bounded time, hence so is $v(t)$ in our solution

Answer (score 1):

The intuitive answer is that you take a solution that goes around $a$ times with $0 \lt a \lt 1$.  Now run the clock backwards.  Unless the solution blows up to $\infty$, you can just continue backwards in time.  Each time you pass the initial angle, read off the angle and velocity and you have an initial condition that will circle a given number of times.  If you prove you can always unwind one more time you are there.

Comment: how does For all $t ≤ 0$, $$E(θ(t), v(t)) ≥ E(2πn, u)$$ $$1/2v(t)^2 + 1 − cos θ(t) ≥ 1/2u^2+2$$  follow?

Comment: For the right hand side, does not $1/2v(t)^2 + 1 - cos(2\pi n)$? If so, since n is all natural number, should not the right hand side become $1/2u^2$?